# Leaflet Marker Comparison (Default Marker VS Marker from Database)

Tags: javascript, php, html, leaflet

How do you deal with Markers in Leaflet? Before I ask my Question I want to show my full code below.

1.Showing the Map from Leaflet to my Site.

```
 <div id="map" style="width: 708px; height: 450px"></div>
    var map = new L.Map('map');
    var osmUrl='http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';
    var osmAttrib='Map data &copy; OpenStreetMap contributors';
    var osm = new L.TileLayer(osmUrl, {minZoom: 15, maxZoom: 18, attribution: osmAttrib});
    map.addLayer(osm);
```

2.Next One is Placing a Default Marker in Map with Pop Up (Leaflet Basics)

```
map.setView([14.7053533,121.031448],15);
L.marker([14.7053533,121.031448]).addTo(map)
            .bindPopup("<b>Hello world!</b><br />I am a popup.").openPopup();
```

3.Next is Generating Marker from Database to Map

```
function getInfo() { 
    $.getJSON("get_info.php", function (data) { 
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
        var location = new L.LatLng(data[i].lat, data[i].lng); 
        var marker = new L.Marker(location); 
           marker.bindPopup(
              data[i].name + "<br>" + 
              data[i].user_date + "<br>" + 
              data[i].user_time + "<br>" + 
              data[i].address + "<br>"
           ).addTo(map);
           marker.on('click', function(e) { // HERE YOU GO
           marker.openpopup();
                var ll = marker.getLatLng();
document.querySelector('#userLat1').value = ll.lat;
document.querySelector('#userLng1').value = ll.lng;
alert('You have selected a Marker that will be deleted'); 

           });
         } 
    }); 
  }
```

Here is the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.leaflet.js:7 o.Popup.o.Class.extend._updateContentleaflet.js:7 o.Popup.o.Class.extend.updateleaflet.js:7 o.Popup.o.Class.extend.onAddleaflet.js:6 o.Map.o.Class.extend._layerAddleaflet.js:6 o.Map.o.Class.extend.addLayerleaflet.js:7 o.Map.include.openPopupleaflet.js?_=1418153335296:7 o.Marker.include.openPopupleaflet.js?_=1418153335296:7 o.Marker.include.togglePopupleaflet.js?_=1418153335296:6 o.Mixin.Events.fireEventleaflet.js?_=1418153335296:7 o.Marker.o.Class.extend._onMouseClickleaflet.js?_=1418153335296:8 t.(anonymous function).s
```

My Question is like this: **No 2**. and **No.3** Codes are using the Leaflet Basics of showing marker in the Map but I have a problem encountered with the two codes. The No.2 is showing a Pop Up when the marker has been clicked but the No.3 **Is Not** how can i fix it? That the Code No.3 will show a pop up when marker is clicked. TY

Comment: Are there any errors in the console when you try No.3?

Comment: Lets say sir that where going to run the code number 3, the output is a marker inside the map(data from database) but when i click it the pop up is not showing, other than that nothing error follows\

Comment: Try using chrome to open your site. Push f12 to open developer tools. Look at the console tab. Is there anything in there?

Comment: Sir this is my first time see this, pls see my edited post to see the error

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation, inside event method you should refer to `this` instead of `marker`. Notice also name of opening popup method: .`openPopup()` not `.openpopup()`.

Try code below:

```
   marker.on('click', function(e) { // HERE YOU GO
      this.openPopup();
      var ll = this.getLatLng();
      document.querySelector('#userLat1').value = ll.lat;
      document.querySelector('#userLng1').value = ll.lng;
      alert('You have selected a Marker that will be deleted'); 
   });
```

Comment: I just copy your code but same error appears in console

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to be adding many markers, why not use `l.featureGroup` and bind the click handler there once, instead of once for each marker?
See example
http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#featuregroup